# Adding A repository to B repository in GitHub

Tags: github, repository, git-merge

I have a A repository with a react-app and B repository with some ML codes in Github. Both repository have some commits and i want to preserve my commits in A repository and add it to the B repository. So i can continue committing on B Repository (ML). How can i do this?

I was trying to add my file to the B repository normally but it doesn't preserve commits.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your Repository B

```
git clone <repository B URL>
```

Navigate into the cloned Repository B directory and add Repository A as a remote.

```
cd <repository B directory>
git remote add repoA <repository A URL>
```

Fetch the commits from Repository A.

```
git fetch repoA
```

Merge the commits from Repository A into Repository B's main branch

```
git merge repoA/main  # or the branch from Repository A you want to merge
```

If there are any conflicts between the commits from Repository A and the existing code in Repository B, resolve them manually. Also keep directory structure compatible

```
git commit -m "Merge commits from Repository A"
```

Push the changes to Repository B.

```
git push origin main
```

Now, you can continue working on Repository B and commit changes as usual.